# How to create multiple pins dynamically on Google Maps in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to create multiple pins on google maps.
My code is like this

In View DidLoad()

```
  //Google Maps...

    _placesClient = [GMSPlacesClient sharedClient];


    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:18.516726
                                                            longitude:73.856255
                                                                 zoom:3];
    mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 140, 350, 350) camera:camera];

    GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
    [path addLatitude:18.516726 longitude:73.856255]; // Sydney
    [path addLatitude:19.0728300 longitude:72.8826100]; // Fiji

    mapView.delegate=self;
    mapView.myLocationEnabled=YES;
    locationtbl.hidden=YES;

    if (nil == locationManager)
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    //Configure Accuracy depending on your needs, default is kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;

    // Set a movement threshold for new events.
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 500; // meters

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    mapView.settings.scrollGestures = YES;
    mapView.settings.zoomGestures = YES;
    mapView.settings.tiltGestures=YES;
    mapView.settings.rotateGestures=NO;
    mapView.settings.compassButton = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
```

Google Delegate method is like this

```
#pragma mark - Google Maps

// Add a UIButton in Interface Builder to call this function
    - (IBAction)pickPlace:(UIButton *)sender {

        CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(18.516726, 73.856255);
        CLLocationCoordinate2D northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude + 0.001,
                                                                      center.longitude + 0.001);
        CLLocationCoordinate2D southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude - 0.001,
                                                                      center.longitude - 0.001);
        GMSCoordinateBounds *viewport = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:northEast
                                                                             coordinate:southWest];
        GMSPlacePickerConfig *config = [[GMSPlacePickerConfig alloc] initWithViewport:viewport];
        _placePicker = [[GMSPlacePicker alloc] initWithConfig:config];

        [_placePicker pickPlaceWithCallback:^(GMSPlace *place, NSError *error) {
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Pick Place error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                return;
            }

            if (place != nil) {
                self.nameLabel.text = place.name;
                self.addressLabel.text = [[place.formattedAddress
                                           componentsSeparatedByString:@", "] componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
            } else {
                self.nameLabel.text = @"No place selected";
                self.addressLabel.text = @"";
            }


 }];
}
```

I am facing issue is to how to show multiple pins on Google Maps.I am getting value from web service in array that is dynamic. I need to show pins [image]on Google Maps like in this Image

H is the pins created on Google Maps which are the Image.How to do this??

I used code like this

```
 for (int i=0; i<NameHSArray.count; i++) {
                CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(18.516726, 73.856255);
                GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
                marker.title = @"Hello World";
                marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mapicon1.png"];
                marker.map = mapView;

            }
```

But when I am adding array it give me error

[image]

Thanks in Advance!

I used this code and its done

```
for (int i=0; i<NameHSArray.count; i++) {
                double LatitudeDouble = [LatitudeHSArray[i] doubleValue];
                double LongitudeDouble = [LongitudeHSArray[i] doubleValue];
                CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(LatitudeDouble, LongitudeDouble);
                GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
                marker.title = NameHSArray[i];
                marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mapicon1.png"];
                GMSCameraUpdate *zoomCamera = [GMSCameraUpdate zoomIn];
                [mapView animateWithCameraUpdate:zoomCamera];
                marker.map = mapView;

            }
```

Comment: string value in array try this [[LattitudeHSArray objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue] 
double value in array then use [LattitudeHSArray objectAtIndex:0]
try this

Answer (score 1):

try this to add map pin on GMSMapView

```
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([lat doubleValue], [lng doubleValue]);
marker.title = "" // you can set marker title here
marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gasoline-pump.png"]; // you can set your image here
marker.snippet = "" // you can set snippet for more details
marker.tracksViewChanges = YES;
marker.tracksInfoWindowChanges = YES;
marker.infoWindowAnchor = CGPointMake(5, 2);
marker.map = mapView;
```

you can remove marker from mapview as follow

```
[mapView clear]; // remove all

marker.mapView = nil //  remove specific
```

---- EDIT ----

set multiple marker as follow

```
for (obj in <#your array#>) {
   GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([lat doubleValue], [lng doubleValue]);
    marker.title = "" // you can set marker title here
    marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gasoline-pump.png"]; // you can set your image here
    marker.snippet = "" // you can set snippet for more details
    marker.tracksViewChanges = YES;
    marker.tracksInfoWindowChanges = YES;
    marker.infoWindowAnchor = CGPointMake(5, 2);
    marker.map = mapView;
}
```

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: covert your string to double

Comment: double myDouble = [myString doubleValue];

Comment: Thanks for your help. This can not happen without you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple pins or icons by creating GMSMarker object. N passing the lat long position with it and assigning icon image if you have one ... or nil if you want default one to be assign

And add that marker object to the GMSMapView Object

```
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([lat doubleValue], [lng doubleValue]);

marker.icon = nil;
marker.map = mapView; // object of GMSMapView
```